# Are questions on Jinn relevant to the IOTA StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

See title -- JINN seems to be linked with IOTA, so to me the answer should be yes, but I thought I would pose it.

Comment: Please add [meta-tag:site-scope].

Comment: Some context about JINN and a way you're leaning would be nice. Otherwise what are we voting on? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: I was thinking of posting a similar question on meta, but I couldn't come up with any example questions that someone might ask (or at least, all the ones I could come up with would be closed as speculative/opinion-based).  But that just means I couldn't think of anything; do you have any ideas for possible on-topic JINN questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, I'd say *of course* because it's been part of IOTA's vision from the outset. The tangle will thrive on this meshed ecosystem of Jinn-PoWin' mini-nodes running on *meellions* of devices.

OTOH, I have this feeling the founders would like to keep it under wraps for now? Linking the ternary processing hardware to the ledger may be undesirable at this point.

Comment: The founders wishes are irrelevant. SE is a separate platform. The relevance of JINN for this site is to be discussed.

Comment: I second what Helmar said on SE being independent from the founders. If we wouldn't allow any questions on JINN in general this would be plain censorship. I think it is a good idea to see and decide from case to case.

Comment: Not pleading for censorship or submission. Trying to understand core team's apparent reluctance to discuss Jinn & link it to IOTA. Their *wishes* are irrelevant indeed -- their *reasoning* may have merit. Though I agree that, if there's no further info to be had, *of course* the topic should be free to dicuss.

Answer (score 2):

I would say no for speculation and yes for facts. But as we know, everything is speculation now.